# Strange sound behavior

Tags: arch-linux, alsa, pulse-audio

First of all, sorry for the tittle. English isn't my native language, and I can't find a word to describe the strange behavior I'm getting here.

In the most simple explanation, is like sound keeps going down and up again...

Think in a kid with that old radios that have a circled volume button. Think like these kid keeps "turning" the volume button. That is the behavior I'm getting here.

At first, I believed that it was a pulseaudio issue, but, it isn't. I followed the [wiki part](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio#Glitches.2C_skips_or_crackling) I think that should be my problem, but it didn't work.

After that, as I'm using XFCE, I didn't really need pulseaudio, so I removed it and stays with a clean alsa, hopping that will fix my problem. Sweet mistake.

It really looks like a kid looking for trouble. I believed it worked, and, suddenly, here is the same issue again.

BTW: I have a full-upgraded testing system (yeah, I upgraded to testing hopping for new pulseaudio version which fix the issue), no pulseaudio at all, just xfce, started with `startxfce`.

What can I do to fix this? It's extremely annoying... sometimes I just want to throw my laptop in the wall because of this.

Any extra info you need, please, tell me.

Thanks in advance

--

EDIT:

My alsamixer is like this:

[image: alsamixer setup]

And [here is a video with the sound behavior](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EGSLahA8EM0).

Comment: I don't see the mixer in your video, but I assume the volume level indicator is not changing, it is only the volume itself that is changing? Also, can you be sure it comes from alsa, and not something else, like a buggy mp3 codec or something?

Comment: Yeah, the mixer doesn't really change, just sounds like it does. Also, it occurs in music, youtube, soundcloud, everywhere.. I believe that's not a codec.. thanks